# Iterate uses of qtip with .each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, qtip

I'm having an issue with getting the Qtip jquery plugin to work over a whole class of html items:

```
$(".peoplebtn").each(function() {
    $(this).qtip({ 
        content: {
            text: $(this).attr('qTipText')
        }
});
});
```

However, when I try this, it throws a Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'qtip'.
I have made sure the qtip script and css is properly included. They should work on img tags such as these:

```
<img class="peoplebtn qtipped" qTipText="Leonardo Dicaprio" onclick="" src="btn/btnf3.png">
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you are including the Qtip JS file and not just the `imagesLoaded.js` file? Are there any other errors in your console (e.g. 404 for the JS file)?

Comment: nope! I am absolutely certain that I have the JS file because I tried a different example and it worked as expected.

Comment: @Tomalak - actually, that is a peculiarity of the QTip library - needed so that you can access the individual element. See http://qtip2.com/guides "A Note on the 'this' Variable" section.

Comment: @steve.hanson Oh I see. What a stupid way to design an API that's intended for jQuery.

Comment: <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.qtip.css" />
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.qtip.js"></script> this is included in the head, I'm certain this is correct

Comment: also, $(".peoplebtn").qtip({
            content: {
                text: $(this).attr('qTipText')
            }
        }); throws a Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'qtip'

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working Fiddle using the same Javascript you posted: http://jsfiddle.net/DVEDv/85/.

I can't help you without more information. The error you are getting sounds like the QTip library failed to load or initialize properly.

HTML:

```
<img qTipText="Hello from img" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="peoplebtn" />
```

JS:

```
$(".peoplebtn").each(function() {
  $(this).qtip({ 
      content: {
          text: $(this).attr('qTipText')
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: this looks right! maybe I have the wrong version of jquery or something

Comment: I have checked and my imports are definitely okay. I should have mentioned previously that I had put this inside a $(document).ready(function() {} jquery block. I have taken the block out and no errors were returned, although now the qtips do not even show. Thoughts?